# Lazy loading in angular 7

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

> Error - >Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: `BrowserModule` has
>   already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as
>   `NgIf` and `NgFor` from a lazy loaded module, import `CommonModule`
>   instead.

In my **app.module** i have imported **sharedmodule**  and all other child modules including sharedModule i have imported `CommonModule`. also I have imported `Browsermodule` once in app module

Comment: could you post your code

Comment: go on the instructions: don't import BrowserModule else in the main.app.module. In others modules you need import CommonModule instead, https://angular.io/guide/frequent-ngmodules#browsermodule-and-commonmodule (in other words: replace in your lazy modules BrowserModule by CommonModule)